# How should I install Ubuntu in my case?

Tags: installation

I tried so hard to download **Ubuntu 12.04** inside Windows but it didn't work. Also I tried to download it on CD and Flash but it didn't work.

1. Can I download Ubuntu 10.10 or 11.10 or another old version from [the Ubuntu home page](http://www.ubuntu.com/)?
2. How can I install it alone (not inside Windows) without using CD or Flash ?

Comment: Why can't you download the iso file in windows? What error are you receiving? Are you able to download other large files? This seems to be a browser or internet connection problem. For connection problem, did you try with a download manager? Did you try with another browser?

Comment: Obs: If you can't download the 12.04 iso file, I don't think you will be able to download older versions as they are about the same size. Anyways, you have to download them to a HD and burn a CD after.

Comment: Alternative would be downloading using Torrent , for [32 bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) and for [64 bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent).

Comment: please clarify your question, are you not able to download or are you not able to install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Could you lease clarify your problem? Are you able to download the Ubuntu 12.04 .iso file?

If not please go to ubuntu.com and follow the downloading procedure. If downloading fails please try another web browser and check that you download is not automatically being downloaded to a folder, usually the "downloads" folder. Note that you CANNOT download ubuntu directly to a cd, you must first download it to a hard drive, then burn it on a cd using a cd burning tool.

Once you have a cd with ubuntu on it, you must put the cd in your computer's cd drive, and then turn off your computer. Then turn you computer on again, if you are lucky you will get a ubuntu loading screen and you can skip the next paragraph, but if windows starts normally turn off you computer and read it.

Turn on your computer  and and PAY ATTENTION! Before windows starts loading, you always get the bios screen, although only for 2 seconds or so. It usually displays the brand of some of your hardware, in my case Acer since I use an Acer laptop. There it will also say "Press xxxx to enter boot/bios menu" or something similar, where xxxx can be Esc, F2, F12.....  Once in there navigate to the boot order, and make sure the cd drive is the first in the list. Once that is done select "save changes" and exit the bios.

If all goes well up to this point, You should get a Ubuntu screen with a few options:

Install Ubuntu while wiping out all other data(make sure to have a backup of ALL your data if you select this, as you WILL lose all of it).

Install Ubuntu beside Windows while conserving all data(dual boot, do your research)

Try out Ubuntu without installing it (no permanent changes, highly recommended so  you can decide whenever you like Ubuntu or not)

Which ever options you chose you will get on-screen explanations from this point on.

Good luck  with your installation, please ask again if you need help!

Answer (score 1):

This must not be a problem with windows or ubuntu. When you are downloading it's just an iso file. My be some problem with your network or browser setting. Or may be there is some problem in server.
As alternative you can try downloading from  torrent also.

Answer (score 0):

you can download some older versions of ubuntu [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) If you can't download 12.04 directly try a [torrent](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) file.it is more faster than the regular download.

why download it alone?....Windows doesn't affect any downloads!...